# Customizer: Output default value in Customizer CSS

Tags: php, theme-development, customization, themes

I've seen the code below in the WordPress [Theme Customization API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API) and several themes to output Customizer CSS in the `head`. It works great but I'm wondering if it can be modified to display a default value, if no value is given for `header_textcolor`, `background_color` or `link_textcolor`.

```
public static function header_output() {
  ?>
  <!--Customizer CSS--> 
  <style type="text/css">
       <?php self::generate_css('#site-title a', 'color', 'header_textcolor', '#'); ?> 
       <?php self::generate_css('body', 'background-color', 'background_color', '#'); ?> 
       <?php self::generate_css('a', 'color', 'link_textcolor'); ?>
  </style> 
  <!--/Customizer CSS-->
  <?php
}

public static function generate_css( $selector, $style, $mod_name, $prefix='', $postfix='', $echo=true ) {
  $return = '';
  $mod = get_theme_mod($mod_name);
  if ( ! empty( $mod ) ) {
     $return = sprintf('%s { %s:%s; }',
        $selector,
        $style,
        $prefix.$mod.$postfix
     );
     if ( $echo ) {
        echo $return;
     }
  }
  return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a default value for `get_theme_mod()` you can pass it as the 2nd argument, like this:

```
$mod = get_theme_mod( 'header_textcolor', '#000000' );
```

That will output `#000000` if there isn't a value saved for `header_textcolor`.

Since your `get_theme_mod()` call is getting the setting from another function, `generate_css()`, you will need to update that function to also send a default:

```
public static function generate_css( $selector, $style, $mod_name, $default, $prefix='', $postfix='', $echo=true ) {
    $return = '';
    $mod = get_theme_mod( $mod_name, $default );
```

I've added it after `$mod_name` in that example.

Then you would update your `header_output()` function to include default values:

```
public static function header_output() {
  ?>
  <!--Customizer CSS--> 
  <style type="text/css">
       <?php self::generate_css('#site-title a', 'color', 'header_textcolor', '#000000', '#'); ?> 
       <?php self::generate_css('body', 'background-color', 'background_color', '#FFFFFF', '#'); ?> 
       <?php self::generate_css('a', 'color', 'link_textcolor', '#0000FF' ); ?>
  </style> 
  <!--/Customizer CSS-->
  <?php
}
```

Now there are default values for those colours.

I think it's worth pointing out though, that your code will not output any CSS if the theme mod doesn't have a value. This means that the default styles will come from your stylesheet. So I'm not sure having defaults here is necessary.

Comment: The reason I want to set the default values here instead of my stylesheet is that I have a lot of checkboxes to display certain settings in the Customizer. I realize I didn't show this above but for example I could have a checkbox to display `background-color` with a conditional statement to only print that style if the checkbox is checked. If using the stylesheet as the default, the default `background-color` would still be displayed when the checkbox in unchecked. I believe this could be confusing to users as they would likely expect no color to be displayed.